# Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: xcode

I know that this question has been asked a million times on this website, but despite looking through all the answers and trying to use these solutions, I was unable to fix my error. I disconnected the outlets and reconnected them, thinking that this might work, but unfortunately not. This being the case, I thought that maybe it could be that I had done something very minor wrong and could be easily fixed. Thanks :)

[FirstViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhDq5.png)

[Productstableviewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0kPo.png)

Comment: Don't post images! Post code (text)! And what exactly is the question? And what is *repeating content*?

Comment: I was asking why I couldn't run the app, as there were errors saying "outlet cannot be connected to repeating content" but it's fixed! Honestly, don't know what I done, but it's fixed now! Thanks